# Optimal way to combine tar.gz files quickly

Tags: linux, bash, java, compression, tar

I am looking for a way to combine multiple *tar.gz* files quickly.

The use case is a client clicks on a download button and proceeds to have a *tar.gz* file delivered to them. There is a configuration option to add additional information to the outbound download in the *GUI* of our application. If this option is selected I am going to need to combine additional *tar.gz* files on to the outbound download.

I am working with a lot of data here. The additional *tar.gz* files are over a GB when uncompressed. In addition, the default *tar.gz* file that is always delivered  can be over 10 GB when uncompressed and can contain over 100 files in it. Due to the large sizes of the data I am working with, it is stored in a compressed format (*tar.gz*) on disk.

I am looking to implement this mechanism either in *Bash* Script or in *Java*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TLDR**: you can usually just concatenate them

The file format usd by `gzip` is designed so that concatenating two or more compressed files and decompressing the result gives you same data as concatenating the uncompressed versions; see 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005114/fast-concatenation-of-multiple-gzip-files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715484/can-multiple-gz-files-be-combined-such-that-they-extract-into-a-single-file

Somewhat similarly the `tar` format was originally designed so that you could just add entries to the end of an archive. This was effectively required because '(t)ape (ar)chive' was designed to and did use magnetic tape for backup and interchange, and the magnetic tape drives of the 1950s-1980s (roughly) could not safely 'rewrite' (update) existing data only add to the end. (Those drives *could* separate logical files on a tape using a 'tape mark' but Unix systems didn't support metadata aka labels on magtape and managing large numbers of tape files by physical numeric position only was a PITA, so the `tar` approach of adding to an existing archive was much preferred.)

In recent years this has become much less common, and GNU tar now doesn't support it by default; you have to specify `-i` (or long form `--ignore-zeros`) and then it works fine:

```
$ printf 'ONEONEONE%90d\n' {0..99999} >file1
$ printf 'TWOTWOTWO%90d\n' {0..199999} >file2
$ ll
total 29300
-rw-r--r--. 1 dthomps users 10000000 Sep  9 02:14 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 dthomps users 20000000 Sep  9 02:15 file2
$ tar -czf tar1.tgz file1
$ tar -czf tar2.tgz file2
    # or tar -cf - file1 |gzip >tar1.tgz and similarly for 2, see below
$ cat tar2.tgz tar1.tgz >combined.tgz
$ tar -tvzif combined.tgz
-rw-r--r-- dthomps/users 20000000 2016-09-09 02:15 file2
-rw-r--r-- dthomps/users 10000000 2016-09-09 02:14 file1
  # or gunzip <combined.tgz |tar -tvif - see below
$
```

Older tars may support concatenating archives by default (no `-i`); if I have time to spin up some of my old test systems later I'll update. However they usually don't support integrated `-z` compression like gtar, so you need to use the `tar cf - | gzip >` and `gunzip < | tar -xf -` forms.

If you use relative paths for files in the archive, as is common and preferred today, when you extract from the concatenated result all the entries (or all the selected ones) are extracted relative to the same new directory, so make sure you create each archive 'piece' with relative paths that work together as desired. If you want file in an appended piece to replace one in the main piece, use the same relative path/name; if you want to create distinct files use distinct relative paths/names.

Comment: You are really a genius. You just gave me a great way to reduce our build time dramatically. Thank you very much. I had tested it in centos of kernel version 3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64 and the `-i` option still exist in tar command and it is this option which did the magic.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I tried it on archives produced by TWRP via `cat data.ext4.win??? | gzip -d -c > data.ext4`, but when I opened `data.ext4` in 7-zip, I only saw data from the first archive.